# Shrinkable space on external harddrive unusually small

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have a 300GB external harddrive. I was going to try and make a partition on it, which includes having to shrink the storage. When I did so, this is what I was shown:

[image: Screenshot]

How could it be so small if I have 112GB still free? I'm running Windows Vista, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yeah, better put this up on superuser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is usually caused my unmovable files on the disk such as system files.

Do a defrag of the external disk and try it again?

You can completely get around it by using something like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).  There are plenty of other free tools out there too.  EASEUS Partition Manager helped me shrink my entire C: drive down and then create a second partition without a hitch.  Prefer GParted though.

Comment: By the way, if you want to go for the slightly easier method which does not involve burning a CD and leaving Windows, EASEUS Partition Manager can be downloaded from http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm. (It works in Vista/Win 7 too.)

Answer (score 0):

I've always been fond of Partition Magic for re-arranging the partitions on a disk. It can generally move around anything it needs to on the disk in order to make room for your new partitioning scheme.